# INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION error message

Tags: adb

So I've been trying to install the google app via ADB, but when i do it i get the following error:

```
[INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox attempting to redeclare permission com.google.android.apps.now.OPT_IN_WIZARD already owned by com.google.android.apps.assistant]
```

I already tried with another app and it worked, im not really sure why this error shows up. Any help?

Comment: Is the Google app you want to install or the mentioned Google assistant app modified (resigned and/or repackaged)? This error indicates that the signature of both apps does not match and thus they can not declare the same custom permission.

Comment: I have the lite versions of these apps, i already uninstalled those but it still gives me the same errror